# make Excel cells read-only using EPPLUS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, epplus

I have following excel data
out of which i wanna make first column and header row read-only.

```
CityMaster        POC       HeadCount
Mumbai          Prasad S       2
Delhi           Kishan T       5
Banglore        Shilpa S       7
Chennai         Prasad S       2
```

Second and third data should be editable.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Make column or cells readonly with EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751808/make-column-or-cells-readonly-with-epplus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked:

```
workSheet.Protection.IsProtected = true;

workSheet.Cells[2, 3, pocDeatils.CityMaster.Rows.Count + 1, 4].Style.Locked = false;
```

for more detail refer below link:
https://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SampleApp/Sample6.cs